# Outlook 2016 - Quick Steps - Removing/Clearing Categories

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using the categories to mark my emails priorities. After an email was handled, via "Quick Step" I want to move this email to a certain folder (e.g. Done) **AND** to remove/clean the assigned category.

In Outlook 2016 I could not find a way to define this. Is it possible to make it in Outlook 2016 ? or MS has removed this option ?

Thanks,
Yuval

Answer (score 0):

Try this "Quick Step", it should do what you want:

[image]

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for the quick response. In the "Quick Step" setup with outlook 2016 , there is no option for "Clear Categories" . Did you add it ? How ?

Comment: @user3604233 It is available in Outlook 2016.

Comment: Are you using an IMAP account? If so, "Clear Categories" is not an option as Color Categories are not supported by IMAP protocol

Answer (score 0):

I do use IMAP . I was able to define categories as you can see below.

[Categories added to ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYklJ.png)

When accessing the "Quick Step" in the ribbon setup, I do see the Categorize & Move but it is shaded. See below.

[ribbon Quick Step setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQBXX.png)

Yuval

Comment: The button in the first screenshot is "Categorized", not "Categorize", click the "Categorized" button and choose a category will do a quick search for items assigned with the selected category.

Comment: For the second screenshot, it just indicates that Categories are not supported by IMAP protocol.